Request to reopen and undelete this question deleted by the Community Bot
I answered the following question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78219908/another-language-in-datagridview-c-sharp-visual-studio



Which now was deleted by the Community bot.
The question is about the tool Visual Studio, which is clearly a tool for programming.
The OP shows in images what result they get, when they add text to a datagridview, which is shown in a second image.
It is clear what the problem is and that it is on topic here, so I answered some questions about tools for programming.
I don't understand why the question was closed in the first place and subsequently deleted.
That the user doesn't understand the workings of Q&A on Stack Overflow, as seen by their own "thank you" answer, is always a problem.

The question is poorly written. At very least, the question's spelling & grammar should be edited into some proper, coherent English. Other than that, I'm not so sure this is on-topic. Sure, Visual Studio is programming software, but front settings? That seems more like a product support question.

I tried to clean up and improve the phrasing of your question, but there are still two problems here 1) it conflates the request to undelete a question with the subject of requiring new users to take the tour, which are very distinct concerns; 2) a request to undelete should also try to make the case for whether that Q&A is likely to be useful in the future.

The question doesn't seem to mention it is about Visual Studio anywhere. Is this something an SME on C# / DataGridView will necessarily know? If not the closure of the question is entirely valid. If you feel that it should be undeleted / reopened please edit and resolve the closure reasons first.

@AbdulAzizBarkat question title.

@Cerbrus I am not an SME but from what I understand Visual Studio provides a visual designer to build Windows Forms apps , and the image shared by the user was apparently an image of their app and the fonts of the app were being controlled by Visual Studio. It can probably be considered a programming problem in that case.

Undeleting wouldn't serve a purpose unless reopened. To see "why" the question was deleted, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

@AbdulAzizBarkat If that's the case then that's something that definitely needs to be cleared up in the question

i havwe seen that the comunity bit has closed it without cuase, i voted already to undelete it

Again, undeleting it without reopening wouldn't be of much use. Have you voted to undelete the question as well? In the end, it is simply a "I configured the wrong font" situation. Wouldn't this at best be a dupe of something like "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69815992/how-to-easily-change-visual-studio-2022-editor-font-and-colors-to-match-vs-2019"?

"It is clear what the problem is" - in your own words, starting with a question word like "how" or "why" and ending with a question mark, what single question do you believe the OP wanted to ask?

At no point in the question is a question asked ... Questions should probably ask a question...

Even when no explcit question is asked, we can determine that he wants to get normal text back, as mine and his  answer clearly indicates, it was the correct answer. so it is simple to deduce that is question can be correctly interpreted

That’s fine for a one on one chat between you and the OP, but that’s not what SO is. 3 other humans don’t deem it to be answerable within the bounds of this site, and that’s why it was closed - because the majority of trusted folks who saw the question weren’t able to make the same inferences that you did

I do think there's a viable question hidden within that question, but until it's edited to be such it's not. (definitely a lot better since the edits today)

This deletion was automatic, because the question met the following criteria:

If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
.

not closed as a duplicate
has a score of 0 or less
is not locked
has no answers with a score > 0
has no accepted answer
has no pending reopen votes
has not been edited in the past 9 days

... it will be automatically deleted. (These are termed "abandoned closed" in the code.)
(source)

Keep in mind that the question will get automatically deleted again, if the question still meets these criteria, after being undeleted.
The easiest solution would be to edit the question in such a way that resolves the closure reason. In its current state, the question is unclear and rather poorly written.
Then, cast an undelete-vote, and with some luck the question will be (and remain) reinstated.

this ia all known to me, and helps not to open the question, so that it can help others with the same problem

I'm not sure what else you expected to get as an answer here, other than an explanation of why it's been deleted, and a pointer on how to get it undeleted, whilst preventing it from being deleted again, @nbk...

this is not hbelpful at all, why was the question closed in the first ace, as it contains all the necessary information and is, clear. i achieved to open it, even when some unknowledgeable people, downvote it and the bit should delete questions that are not downvoted.

Please at least consider putting effort into making sure comments are free of typos, before trying to make claims about what's clear or should be deemed to meet site standards.

@KarlKnechtel It's clear from their posts & comments that they want the typos.

@nbk I explained why it was closed: "In its current state, the question is unclear and rather poorly written." The suggestion that downvoters are "unknowledgeable" is rather toxic. You're attributing a curative action to malice or lack of intelligence, that's very unconstructive.
